# TeXmaker not compiling on OSx El Capitan (error: log file not found)

Tags: errors, texmaker, mac

When I try to compile pdfLaTeX on TeXmaker, it doesn't seem to be working. It used to work on Yosemite before I updated the operating system to OSx El Capitan. I have changed all the /usr/texbin commands to /Library/TeX/texbin as described in the following document by Herbert Shultz: https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf.

A pop-up error comes up when I try to compile saying 'Log file not found'. I am a very new LaTeX user so please explain as simply as possible how to fix this.

P.S It doesn't seem to be working for TeXShop (3.57) either.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Can you compile a document from the command line, with something like `pdflatex myfile`?

Comment: Did you check similar questions? I saw several of them the last few weeks

Comment: Hi @Mike, I don't know how to compile a document from the command line with pdflatex myfile. (I don't actually know what that is.

Comment: I did check some similar questions but I couldn't find anything that helped me @sztruks. Thanks

Comment: Save a very simple document named myfile.tex file in your home directory. Open up Terminal from the Applications / Utilities folder in Finder. At the `$` prompt, type `pdflatex myfile` and the Return key. If it succeeds and creates `myfile.pdf`, you have a TeXmaker problem. If it fails, you may not have MacTeX installed properly.

Comment: Hi @Mike, I tried to do this and I'm getting the following error: 

Last login: Fri Nov  6 16:24:38 on console
Vatsals-MacBook-Air:~ Vatsal$ pdflatex myfile
-bash: pdflatex: command not found.

Perhaps it is because I saved the file on my desktop? I don't know what the home directory is on a mac. I tried putting the file in the my 'documents' folder as well, which produced the same error.

Comment: No, that's an indication you either have no MacTeX at all, or a horribly botched install of MacTeX. I'd just recommend reinstalling MacTeX 2015.

Comment: Hi thanks, this seemed to work. I actually had MacTex 2014 installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it as follows:
Notice that you do not have to change *all* the `/usr/texbin` to
`/Library/TeX/texbin`.
The path for `latexmk` must remain as `/usr/texbin`.
In my case this fixed the problem.